# getting error code 1 (error or missing database) when trying to insert into database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm having a problem with creating a table, as attempting to insert into it gives me the follow result:

```
 Error Code : 1 (SQLITE_ERROR)
    Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database.
        (near "VALUES": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO PointTable (longitudeValue, latitudeValue, date, isLeaving, isArrinving, engineRpm, engineLoad, manAbsPressure, batteryLvl, airTemperature, airFlowRate, speed) VALUES)
```

The table already existed and worked before, the problem occured as I tried to add the values that come after "isArrinving".

I create my table as seen in the following code:

```
   private static final String CREATE_POINT_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_POINT + "("
        + KEY_ID_POINT + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + KEY_LONGITUDE + " TEXT, " + KEY_LATITUDE + " TEXT, "
        + KEY_DATE + " DATE, " + KEY_LEAVING + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0, " + KEY_ARRIVAL + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0, " +
        KEY_ENGINE_RPM + " TEXT, " + KEY_ENGINE_LOAD + " TEXT, " + KEY_ABS_PRESSURE + " TEXT, " + KEY_BATTERY_LEVEL + " TEXT, " + KEY_AIR_TEMPERATURE + " TEXT, " + KEY_AIRFLOW_RATE
        + " TEXT, "  + KEY_SPEED + " TEXT " + ");";
```

And I attempt to insert into it as shown in the following code:

```
   public void addFirstPoint(JSONObject point) {
        String request = "INSERT INTO " + TABLE_POINT + " (" + KEY_LONGITUDE + ", " + KEY_LATITUDE + ", " + KEY_DATE + ", " + KEY_LEAVING + ", " + KEY_ARRIVAL + ", "
                + KEY_ENGINE_RPM + ", " + KEY_ENGINE_LOAD + ", " + KEY_ABS_PRESSURE + ", " + KEY_BATTERY_LEVEL + ", " + KEY_AIR_TEMPERATURE+ ", " + KEY_AIRFLOW_RATE+ ", " + KEY_SPEED + ") VALUES  ";
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        try {
            request = request.concat(" ('" + point.getString("Longitude") + "', '" + point.getString("Latitude") + "', '" + point.getString("Date") + "', '"
                    + point.getBoolean("Begin") + "', '" + point.getBoolean("End") + "', '" + point.getString("engineRPM") + "', '" + point.getString("engineLoad")
                    + "', '" + point.getString("manAbsPressure") + "', '" + point.getString("batteryLvl") + "', '" + point.getString("airTemperature") + "', '"
                    + point.getString("airFlowRate") + "', '" + point.getString("speed") + "')");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

            db.execSQL(request);

        db.close();
    }
```

I've perused these forums for solutions but unfortunately haven't been able to find anything helpful.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are catching any exception when extracting values from the JSON object and continuing any missing values (including mis-typed or omitted) then you would likely get an SQL error, which appears to be the issue as the SQL in the error message is incomplete (indicating that the exception is likely with the very first value).

As such your issue is likely with the JSON.

I'd suggest using :-

```
public void addFirstPoint(JSONObject point) {
    // Must be 12 
    if (point.length() != 12) {
        Log.d("ADDFIRSTPOINT","Unable to add, the JSON object does not have 12 values.");
        return;
    }
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    try {
        cv.put(KEY_LONGITUDE,point.getString("Longitude"));
        cv.put(KEY_LATITUDE,point.getString("Latitude"));
        cv.put(KEY_DATE,point.getString("Date"));
        cv.put(KEY_LEAVING,point.getBoolean("Begin"));
        cv.put(KEY_ARRIVAL,point.getBoolean("End"));
        cv.put(KEY_ENGINE_RPM,point.getString("engineRPM"));
        cv.put(KEY_ENGINE_LOAD,point.getString("engineLoad"));
        cv.put(KEY_ABS_PRESSURE,point.getString("manAbsPressure"));
        cv.put(KEY_BATTERY_LEVEL,point.getString("batteryLvl"));
        cv.put(KEY_AIR_TEMPERATURE,point.getString("airTemperature"));
        cv.put(KEY_AIRFLOW_RATE,point.getString("airFlowRate"));
        cv.put(KEY_SPEED,point.getString("speed"));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
    db.insert(TABLE_POINT,null,cv);
    db.close();
}
```

This will :-

- first test that there are 12 values
- build the SQL based solely upon values

  - values are enclosed
  - clauses are correctly generated and ordered
- not attempt to run if any values are omitted

**Note** The above will not fix the underlying issue, you would probably see *Unable to add, the JSON object does not have 12 values.* in the log.

**The fix is to correct the issues with the JSON object.**

P.S. The table creation appears to be good (i.e. works when tested).